# Javascript (JQuery) and Bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am currently working on a project that displays some information about movies(pulled from omdbapi.com) in a modal depending on the link that is clicked.  Previously this was all done using PHP in the back end and was working without any issues, but as a page can have anywhere from 5-100 movie links on it, creating all of the modals was causing the page to take a while to load.

Now I want to move the modal creation/popup to the front with JS so that it is only created when and if that particular movie link is clicked.  Moving it to use Javascript I have encountered two issues I am not able to solve.

1. The movie title link must be clicked twice in order for the modal to appear and I am not sure what is causing this.  Looking at the dev tools I can see that on the first click a modal is created, but for some reason not displayed. On the second click another is created and displayed.
2. Once a modal is displayed I am unable to get my "X" button to close it. The code I was using in PHP`"<button type=\"button\" class=\"close exit-button\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">&times;</button>"`
   no longer works.  Bootstrap does have the ability to show/hide a modal with `$("#movieInfo").modal("hide")`, but if I create a function to run this when the button is clicked it still does not hide.

Here is the JS code that I am using:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
var movielink = document.getElementById("movie");
movielink.addEventListener("click", function(){generateModal(this.innerHTML);}, false);
}, false);

function generateModal(movieT) {
    var movieTitle = encodeURIComponent(movieT).replace(/%20/g, '+');
    var url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+movieTitle+"&y=&plot=short";
    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        $('#modalContainer').html("<div id = \"movieInfo\" class = \"modal fade\" role = \"dialog\">"
            + "<div class \"modal-dialog modal-sm\">"
            + "<div class = \"modal-content\">"
            + "<div class = \"modal-body\">"
            + "<div class = \"poster\">"
            + "<img src = "+json.Poster+" width = 200 height = 300>"
            + "</div>"
            + "<div class = \"movie-specs\">"
            + "<button id = \"closebtn\" type=\"button\" class=\"close exit-button\"s onclick = \"closeModal()\">&times;</button>"
            + "<h3 class = \"movie-title\">"+json.Title+" ("+json.Year+")</h3>"
            + "<p class = \"topmargin-gone\">"+json.Rated+" | "+json.Runtime+" | "+json.Genre+"</p>"
            + "<p class = \"topmargin-gone\">"+json.Released+"</p><hr>"
            + "<div class = \"ratingInfo\">"
            + "<h4 class = \"topmargin-gone\"><strong>Ratings</strong></h4><p class = \"topmargin-gone\">Rated: "+json.imdbRating+"/10 "
            + "from "+json.imdbVotes+" users | Metascore: "+json.Metascore+"</p>"
            + "</div><hr>"
            + "<div class = \"plot-actors\">"
            + "<p>"+json.Plot+"</p><p><strong>Director: </strong>"+json.Director+"</p>"
            + "<p><strong>Writers: </strong>"+json.Writer+"</p>"
            + "<p><strong>Actors: </strong>"+json.Actors+"</p>"
            + "</div>"
            + "</div>"
            + "</div>"
            + "</div>"
            + "</div>"
            + "</div>");
    });
    $("#movieInfo").modal("show");

}
```

This is how the the links are created inside a loop in PHP:

```
$allDisplay .= "<li><em><a id ='movie' href = '#'>"
                 . "$title[$z]</a></em> - $nominees[$z]</li>";
```

And finally this is how the HTML looks where the links and modal reside:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Award Search</title>
    <!-- jQuery Library -->
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Styles CSS sheet -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/src/styles/styles_awardQuery.css">
    <!--Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "/src/php/modalCreation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "site-wrapper">
        <div class = "site-wrapper-inner">
            <div class = "cover-container">
                <div class = "masthead clearfix">
                    <div class = "inner">
                        <h3 class = "masthead-brand">Award Search</h3>
                        <ul class = "nav masthead-nav">
                            <li><a href = "/src/pages/welcomePage.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "/src/pages/aboutLoggedIn.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "/src/pages/logoutPage.php">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class = "inner cover">
                    <h1 class = "cover-heading">Academy Award Show Number <?php echo $academyNumber; ?>
                    <?php echo "($year[1])<br><span class = \"small\">Hosted by $acHost</span>"; ?></h1>
                    <?php echo $allDisplay; ?>
                    <div id ="modalContainer"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I realize this looks messy, but just want to get it functioning right now.  If anyone has any insight into either of the issues it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$("#movieInfo").modal("show");` is triggered **before** the bloc was actually append to your web page. This is due to the network latency and the Async behaviour of AJAX call that allow your script to continue without waiting to get an answer.

To avoid this, you should put this line **at the end of the network callback** :

```
function generateModal(movieT) {
    var movieTitle = encodeURIComponent(movieT).replace(/%20/g, '+');
    var url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+movieTitle+"&y=&plot=short";
    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        $('#modalContainer').html('<div id="movieInfo" class="modal fade" role="dialog">'
            + '<div class "modal-dialog modal-sm">'
            + '<div class="modal-content">'
            + '<div class="modal-body">'
            + '<div class="poster">'+'<img src='+json.Poster+' width=200 height=300>'+'</div>'
            + '<div class="movie-specs">'
            + '<button id="closebtn" type="button" class="close exit-button"s onclick="closeModal()">&times;</button>'
            + '<h3 class="movie-title">'+json.Title+' ('+json.Year+')</h3>'
            + '<p class="topmargin-gone">'+json.Rated+' | '+json.Runtime+' | '+json.Genre+'</p>'
            + '<p class="topmargin-gone">'+json.Released+'</p><hr>'
            + '<div class="ratingInfo">'
            + '<h4 class="topmargin-gone"><strong>Ratings</strong></h4><p class="topmargin-gone">Rated: '+json.imdbRating+'/10 '
            + 'from '+json.imdbVotes+' users | Metascore: '+json.Metascore+'</p>'
            + '</div><hr>'
            + '<div class="plot-actors">'
            + '<p>'+json.Plot+'</p><p><strong>Director: </strong>'+json.Director+'</p>'
            + '<p><strong>Writers: </strong>'+json.Writer+'</p>'
            + '<p><strong>Actors: </strong>'+json.Actors+'</p>'
            + '</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>');

        // after we have made the modal, we show it
        $("#movieInfo").modal("show");
    });
    // code here will be fired before the end of the AJAX call
}
```

For your other bug, I think the double modal may explain the behaviour, so patch this first, and told us if you still can't close your modal ;)

Comment: This was was the issue! This solution corrected both problems.  I had not realized that the AJAX call was not synchronized to the rest of the script.

Comment: @bcBorn you're welcome ! ; so yes, the ajax call is usually in async mode, to prevent a full page freez if you got some network problem, that's why you use "callback", that'll be call after the success/fail of your request ;)